# Hide android default keyboard as I have my own number pad in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, keyboard

I have my own number keypad. I need edittext but I do not need the keypad.
Am doing this project in kotlin. There is an answer here [Is there any way to permanently hide soft keyboard but keep enabling focus for an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046241/is-there-any-way-to-permanently-hide-soft-keyboard-but-keep-enabling-focus-for-a)  and also [How do you close/hide the Android soft keyboard using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-do-you-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-using-java) however i could not find the code in kotlin.
**I need code in kotlin** .
Thanks in advance.

https://snipboard.io/qZ0fYW.jpg i copied Java code and Android Studio converted it to java but it failed and giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either do:

```
calcET.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                //code here
            }

        })
```

notice the **brackets are removed** and the **override** keyword added

or simply:

```
calcET.setOnClickListener {
            //code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension to hide Keyboard

```
 fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
     val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
     InputMethodManager 
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById<View>. 
     (android.R.id.content).windowToken,0) 
 }
```